# NoSuchMethodError when submitting Flink job

Tags: java, apache-flink

I am trying to connect Flink with Cassandra. I'm running the sample program from [Github](https://github.com/apache/flink/blob/master/flink-streaming-connectors/flink-connector-cassandra/src/test/java/org/apache/flink/streaming/connectors/cassandra/example/CassandraPojoSinkExample.java), but I get the following error:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:
>   org.apache.flink.streaming.api.datastream.DataStreamSink.name(Ljava/lang/String;)Lorg/apache/flink/streaming/api/datastream/DataStreamSink;
>     at
>   org.apache.flink.streaming.connectors.cassandra.CassandraSink$CassandraPojoSinkBuilder.build(CassandraSink.java:325)

Comment: I'm not trying to run it on cluster..I'm trying to run it locally

Comment: What build tool do you use ?

Answer (score 3):

A `NoSuchMethodError` usually indicates a version mismatch.

Is your program compiled against the same Flink version as the cluster you are trying to run it on?